# Set up Notifications in Android application?

Tags: java, android

I have app for job search, it works over httppost to activate PHP function and get filtered(depends what kind of search user choose)data(JSon format) from mysql database on server. 
What I want to do now is to put one checkbox for notifications, and if user check it before click on search, to be able to get notifications in Status bar about new jobs he didn't see at the first time, for example ("You have 10 new jobs in your search"). And after he click on notification application will open on the page with the list of jobs he already seen + new jobs, just I want to somehow show user which jobs are new. 
I was thinking that maybe I can wrap the new data in a different color. 
Can anyone give me idea how can I do it? 
And how can I now when database have new data, how to monitor it?

Answer (score 0):

Register a [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) onto the database, and upon changing, you update the notification that you currently have (via the same notification ID).

Comment: I'm not sure that I can understand you.
How can I register a ContentObserver into mysql database on server???
Over there is all data, which I catch and convert into JSon.
When database data change, I mean when someone add new jobs into database I want to Android user receive notification.